# How do I lower the post game mega stone price for charizard?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I beat the elite four, beat the rival again and went to buy Mega Stones for Charizard because I chose Bulbasaur in the beginning.

Yet the clerks sells me the stone with a price tag of 1000000. What's going on? Is there any way to lower its price?

Answer (score 5):

The prices for many things in Lumiose City (Stone Emporium, Boutique Couture) are linked to a "stylish" stat. There are certain things you can do in Lumiose City that increase this stat such as:

- Participating in the restaurant battles
- Helping out at the Hotel
- Buying clothes at Boutique Couture
- Getting a haircut
- Talking to Alexa at the Lumiose Press
- And more...

Increasing your "stylishness" will get you such bonuses as discounts at the various Lumiose stores, more hairstyling options, more options at the Juice Bar, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (although arguably lame and kind of "cheaty") and probably cheapest way is to buy a bunch of Premier Balls.
Make sure you buy them one by one and regularly check back with the Stone guy once you have over 100. It is not necessary to exit the store or the buy dialog, you can simply select the Premier Ball and mash A.

I personally needed roughly 120 Premier Balls to unlock the lowest price (which is 10.000 by the way), but I did some style-raising actions before that, so I assume 150 should do if you start at 0 style.
Don't believe the reports on the Internet which say you need 100. They're based on wrong observations because the people trying it had done more things to raise their style before starting to buy Premier Balls.